# Cannot call use class name directly to map type after adding a companion project

Tags: scala, traits, companion-object

When we have a case class, we call map the type with the name of the type, e.g.:

```
case class Foo(value: String)
val value = Some("Yay!")
val foo = value.map(Foo)
```

But if we also provide a companion object, this stops working `value.map(Foo)` and looks like this works: `value.map(Foo(_))`. Why?

```
case class Foo(value: String)
object Foo {}
val value = Some("Yay!")
val foo = value.map(Foo)
println(foo)
```

> ScalaFiddle.scala:5: error: type mismatch;
>    found   : ScalaFiddle.this.Foo.type
>    required: scala.this.Function1[lang.this.String,?]
>     val foo = value.map(Foo)

Comment: I just paste the code in the RELP and it worked _(scala 2.12.7)_, which Scala version are you using? or can you provide a more complete example that does fail?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I just tried it in a worksheet and it doesn't work: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/nXeDmV1/0 - what did you do to make it compile?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, code added, and we're running 2.11.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't define `object Foo` at all, then the synthetic companion object has the following declaration:

```
<synthetic> object Foo 
   extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1[String,Foo] 
      with Serializable
```

But if you define your own `object Foo` as follows

```
case class Foo(v: String)
object Foo {}
```

then the declaration of the `Foo` object changes accordingly to:

```
object Foo extends scala.AnyRef with Serializable
```

and it no longer `extend`s `Function1`.

The method `apply(v: String): Foo` is still automatically generated on `Foo`, but it no longer implements the `Function1[String, Foo]` interface. If you declare the companion object like this:

```
object Foo extends (String => Foo) { ... }
```

then you again can use it in expressions like `value.map(Foo)`.

---

The `value.map(Foo(_))` syntax always works, because it's just a shortcut for

```
value.map(x => Foo.apply(x))
```

and the closure doesn't care at all about what interfaces are implemented by `Foo`, it cares only about the existence of the `apply` method.

Comment: The [specs](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes) don't require the `extends (String => Foo)`. I guess that it is an implementation detail (?)

Comment: @Yaneeve What do you mean by "require"? It does not *guarantee* that the `Function1[String, Foo]`-trait will be added to the declaration: if you define your own `object Foo`, you are on your own. The spec doesn't seem to say much about the interfaces implemented by the synthetic companion objects. It's just underspecified. It seems that they added the `Function1`-trait in the later versions.

Comment: By require I meant specified. I will settle for your assumption that it is _underspecified_.